# Check if string contains an isolated word

Tags: regex, abap

When I'm searching for a word in a string, I usually do it something like this:

```
CONSTANTS:
      lc_word TYPE string VALUE 'TEST',
      .

IF ls_structure-name CS lc_word.
      "count( ).
ENDIF.
```

But this time I only want it to be true if the word is isolated and case sensitive.
For example:

- `TESTer`, `Test` should not count
- `TEST`, `lol TEST`, `TEST yourself`, `hi TEST yourself` should count

Does someone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: If you first split into words, you can then test if the word is all upper case (`if word = to_upper( word ).`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex check:

```
FIND REGEX '(\s|^)TEST(\s|$)' IN ls_structure-name.

IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      "count( ).
ENDIF.
```

It checks for the following pattern:

- Whitespace or the beginning of the string
- 'test'
- Whitespace or the end of the string

Comment: @Samleijenhorst : Your solution works for the test cases provided by OP but generelly I'd suggest to use the designated `\b` for word boundaries instead of whitespace characters `\s` since word boundaries are exactly what OP asked for and there are edge cases not covered by `\s`

Comment: @konstantin do you have an example for an edge case?

Comment: @Cold_Class If your word is followed by any special character after "TEST" like e.g. a comma. Check these examples: https://regex101.com/r/KogWop/2 . With `\b` they're all fine: https://regex101.com/r/KogWop/3 .

Answer (score 0):

You can split your sentence into table, then check if it exists in tale. Like this:

```
DATA: lv_string TYPE string VALUE 'One two TEST three',
      lv_var    TYPE string VALUE 'TEST',
      lv_count  TYPE i.


SPLIT lv_string AT space INTO TABLE DATA(lt_string).
IF line_exists( lt_string[ table_line = lv_var ] ).
  lv_count = lv_count + 1.
ENDIF.
WRITE: / lv_count.
```